# Typescript Collections not initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Background:
I have a jquery click function which should delete a picture from a model. For that I am sending an ajax request to my controller. To get the URL of this action I wrote an ActionResolver which works similar to the HTML helper of MVC. As you see in the code I used typescript and typescript collections.

My problem now is that as soon as the browser reaches "var routeValues = new collections. Dictionary();" it errors with "Uncaught ReferenceError: collections is not defined". I wrote at the top of the ts file "/// < reference path="typings/collections/collections.ts" />" so I can't figure out why it's not defined.

If anyone has a hint I would really appreciate it as I am just getting started with jscript and typedscript. :)

```
$(function () {
    $(".jsPictureDelete").click(function () {
        var controller = $("#Controller").attr('value');
        var id = $("#Id").attr('value');
        var propertyName = this.id.replace("pictureDeleteBtn", "");

        var routeValues = new collections.Dictionary<string, string>();
        routeValues.setValue("id", id);
        routeValues.setValue("propertyName", propertyName);

        var action : Action = new Action("DeletePicture", controller, routeValues);

        //var url = '/' + controller + '/DeletePicture/' + id + '?propertyName=' + propertyName;
        var url = action.ResolveAction();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (returndata : any) {
                alert("worked");
            }
        });
    });
});

class Action {
    private _controller: string;
    private _action: string;
    private _routevalues = new collections.Dictionary<string, string>();
    constructor(action: string, controller: string, routevalues = new collections.Dictionary<string, string>()) {
        this._controller = controller;
        this._action = action;
        this._routevalues = routevalues;
    }
    public ResolveAction() : string {
        var result: string = "/" + this._controller + "/" + this._action;
        var attrib: boolean = false;
        if (this._routevalues.containsKey("id")) {
            result += "/" + this._routevalues.getValue("id") + "?";
        }
        Object.keys(this._routevalues).forEach(function (key) {
            if (key !== "id") {
                result += key + "=" + this._routevalues[key] + "&";
                attrib = true;
            }
        });
        if (attrib) {
            result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

referencing the collections.ts file only provides intellisense support in the editor.
you have to include that file (js equivalent?) in your webpage too.

Comment: Solved the problem :) Obviously a beginner fail

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile it with the `--out` flag.

Reference: https://youtube.com/watch?hd=1&v=KDrWLMUY0R0

Comment: I am working in visual studio so it compiles on its own. My mistake was that I didn’t include collections.js file into my bundles. I installed it with NuGet so everything worked pretty much out of the box except some errors which the collections.ts had duo to an update of VS I guess.